# Java class in Oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I have an Oracle 12 database and I'm trying to load a Java function so that it can be called from PL/SQL.

I've written a NetBeans project to test my function and it works fine.
However, inside Oracle, it cannot compile.
One factor is that it references a library of about 75 jar files. 
I loaded these jars into the database earlier using

```
loadjava -u ......... *.jar -jarasresource
```

(These are the same jars that are part of the NetBeans library.)

The source was loaded into the database using loadjava:

```
loadjava -u .........  -r -v -genmissing PictureGenerator.java
```

The error messages mention the classes in the import statements.

StandardCharsets is part of the JDK, isn't it?

The other imported classes are included in the jar files I loaded.

Please tell me what to do to get my class to resolve within Oracle.

Here's the source:

```
package gov.nlm.structuredepictor;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import chemaxon.formats.MolExporter;
import chemaxon.formats.MolImporter;
import chemaxon.struc.Molecule;

public class PictureGenerator
{
  public static byte[] getPngForMol(String molString, String sbFormat)
  {
    MolImporter mi = null;
    try
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(molString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        if (inStream == null)
        {
            System.err.print("Error creating ByteArrayInputStream");
            return null;
        }
        mi = new MolImporter(inStream);
        Molecule mol = mi.read();

        mi.close();

        byte[] b = MolExporter.exportToBinFormat(mol, sbFormat);
        return b;

    } catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creeating MolImporter: " + ex1.getMessage());
        //Logger.getLogger(PictureGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Thanks for the suggestion about the JDK version!  I changed the DB to use JDK 7 and was able to compile without errors.   The next step was to declare the PL/SQL function 
    create or replace function getPngForMol(molString varchar2, sbFormat             varchar2) return raw
                as LANGUAGE JAVA
   Name    'gov.nlm.structuredepictor.PictureGenerator.getPngForMol(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
return byte[]';

This compiled without error.  However, at runtime, I get this error:
Error report -
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
ORA-06512: at "CHEM.GETPNGFORMOL", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 11
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.

Does this suggest anything?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Posting the exact error message is always helpful.  The `StandardCharsets` documentation seems to indicate this was introduced in Java 1.7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html  By default, Oracle 12.1 supports JDK 6 though you can change that to support JDK 7 https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chone.htm#JJDEV13628